# Is it possible to add a UIImage to CPTGraph?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-plot

I'm trying to add an image to a graph using Core-Plot and I want the image to move along with the graph when it being dragged or pinched. I've tried the code below but it didn't work. Can anyone tell me how to do so?

```
CALayer *subLayer = [CALayer layer];
subLayer.contents = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
subLayer.position = CGPointMake(100, 120);
[_graph addSublayer:subLayer];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a plot space annotation:

```
CPTBorderedLayer *imageLayer = [[CPTBorderedLayer alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
imageLayer.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:[CPTImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];

NSArray *plotPoint = @[xCoordinate, yCoordinate];
CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *imageAnnotation = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:plotSpace
                                                                            anchorPlotPoint:plotPoint];
imageAnnotation.contentLayer = imageLayer;
```